# Client App with WCF to consume ASMX

Tags: c#, wcf, asmx

I have a webservice with .NET 1.1 (old school ASMX) and I am creating a client app to connect to it and use its services.
From what I remember from the last time I had used Visual studio -which was 2003 version!-  I can add a WebReference to it and easily use it. Tried it . it still works. 
but it looks like things have changed in 2008 and now we also have WCF. so I can add it as a Service Reference. but with this new method I could not find a way to create an Instance object to the ASMX service and call its methods... how do we accomplish the same thing with WCF?

Comment: looks like I should have a Channel (?)
how to init it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. done:
we should create a ServiceSoapClinet . an example from my play app:

```
using (LatestServiceSoapClient proxy = new LatestServiceSoapClient("LatestServiceSoap"))
{
    label1.Text = proxy.Welcome();
}
```